# SQL: What does 'AS' do in the context of creating procedures?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

```
CREATE PROCEDURE filepath.foo.Customer_Cork
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT *
    FROM CUSTOMER
    WHERE COUNTY = 'Cork';
END;
```

I have the code above. What exactly does `AS` do in it?

Also, how is my indentation/formatting/semi-colon placement? I'm not that versed in SQL so I'd appreciate any tips in making my code better.

Comment: As far as I know, it's just an arbitrary token that denotes the beginning of a stored procedure definition.  You can define parameters in between your name and definition, `AS` just says, "everything after me is part of the actual definition."

Comment: semicolon goes after each statement (if you want me to be happy, that is). So you could have one after `'Cork'`;` You should also be in the habit of explicitly putting the schema in your tables so `foo.CUSTOMER` I find it's helpful to always alias the table and then always alias the columns. slan

Comment: @billinkc If you're happy, I'm happy. I'm always looking to improve my formatting. Does that look fine now? I'm not following you about putting my schema in my tables. And to alias, I would insert something like `AS Customer_Alias` after `FROM CUSTOMER`, correct? Go raibh maith agat! :)

Comment: @Jens If I understand your question, none in particular. Just general SQL I believe. We've used command line and Ingres. This code was gotten from a video where he was using Microsoft SQL Server.

Comment: In the SQL Server world, objects belong in containers called schemas. They can be used for security, logical separation, etc. [Ingres](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ingres_(database)#Tables) supports the concept. Rather than use an implicit object search, be specific about the table you want. It can make for better, reusable query plans as well as remove the opportunity for unexpected behaviour. While * is a convenient notation, it doesn't lead to maintainable code. I use a succinct alias myself so the rewrite would be `SELECT C.foo, C.bar, C.County FROM dbo.CUSTOMER AS C WHERE C.COUNTY='Cork'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is used as a seperator between the header(*where you define your input parameter*) and the body(*where you define your logic*) of the stored procedure. Also you can take it as the starting point of your logic ie, after the AS everything else will contain the logic for your stored procedure.

Your indentation is good. So no issues with that.

**On a side note:**

SQL was once referred to as "[Structured English Query Language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL)". So probably the language writers tried to use a relevant word which may help us identify the seperator. :)

Answer (score 1):

Simply put, `AS` separates the header and parameter list from the body of the procedure.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE filepath.foo.Customer_Cork
    --(empty) parameter list
AS --body starts here
BEGIN
    SELECT *
    FROM CUSTOMER
    WHERE COUNTY = 'Cork'
END;
```

Indentation/formatting is really a matter of personal style, but what you have looks pretty good to me.

Answer (score 1):

It is used to declare the package **body**.
After you define your IN or OUT parameters in your package head, you are now declaring that the head definition *AS* the body that follows.

Also, your indentation and semicolon use is fine. It's best to indent every level in (as you have done) and all `BEGIN ... END` blocks are terminated with `;`.